# Why simple aql execute returns AsyncJobResultError when client requests data?

Tags: python, asynchronous, arangodb, fastapi, python-arango

Simple aql execute queries return this error too often.

```
arango.exceptions.AsyncJobResultError: [HTTP 204] job 4739915 not done
```

Sometimes it returns the data and sometime it doesn't while throwing above error.

Example query is below.

```
# here db is an instance of AsyncDatabase of python-arango library
# which is retreived by arangoClient.begin_async_execution 
cursor = db.aql.execute(f"""
  LET test = (
    FOR c IN TestCol
      FILTER c.status == @status
      COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO length
      RETURN length
     )
  return {{
    "test": test[0],
    "status": SomeStatus
  }}
""").results()

# to consume cursor
res = [x for x in cursor]
```

Comment: Did you try to close brackets in return{{.. statement

Comment: Yes that's a non issue here, as it is just an example. The real query gives results just fine but fails when requested multiple times by client. I think the async job remains unfinished if it is requested too often and then throws this error.